# How to use Substring when String length is not fixed everytime

Tags: java, string

I have string something like :

```
SKU: XP321654
Quantity: 1
Order date: 01/08/2016
```

The `SKU` length is not fixed , so my function sometime returns me the first or two characters of **Quantity** also which I do not want to get. I want to get only SKU value.

My Code :

```
int index = Content.indexOf("SKU:");
String SKU = Content.substring(index, index+15);
```

If SKU has one or two more digits then also it is not able to get because I have specified limit till `15`. If I do **index + 16** to get long SKU data then for Short SKU it returns me some character of **Quantity** also.

How can I solve it. Is there any way to use instead of a static string character length as limit.

My `SKU` last digit will always number so any other thing which I can use to get only `SKU` till it's last digit?

Comment: You can use regex instead of substring...

Comment: @Idos - I tried but did not get data in format which I want. Can you please help?

Comment: Or you can find index of 'SKU' and 'Quantity', then the String between those is required string SKU number

Comment: you can split by newline then you will only have first line http://ideone.com/xIOh2C

Comment: Does the string contain line breaks like you posted?

Comment: @HelpingHands is it a file that you're parsing ? It does not really make sense to consider it as a single string whereas there are 3 independent lines

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `.substring` is simply not the way to process such things. What you need is a *regex* (or regular expression):

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("SKU\\s*:\\s*(\\S+)");
String sku = null;

Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(Content);
if(matcher.find()) {  //we've found a match
    sku = matcher.group(1);
}
//do something with sku
```

Unescaped the regex is something like:

```
SKU\s*:\s*(\S+)
```

you are thus looking for a pattern that starts with `SKU` then followed by zero or more `\s` (spacing characters like space and tab), followed by a colon (`:`) then potentially zero or more spacing characters (`\s`) and finally the part in which you are interested: one or more (that's the meaning of `+`) non-spacing characters (`\S`). By putting these in brackets, these are a *matching group*. If the regex succeeds in finding the pattern (`matcher.find()`), you can extract the content of the matching group `matcher.group(1)` and store it into a string.

Potentially you can **improve the regex** further **if you for instance know more about how a SKU looks like**. For instance if it consists only out of uppercase letters and digits, you can replace `\S` by `[0-9A-Z]`, so then the pattern becomes:

```
Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("SKU\\s*:\\s*([0-9A-Z]+)");
```

**EDIT**: for the quantity data, you could use:

```
Pattern pat2 = Pattern.compile("Quantity\\s*:\\s*(\\d+)");
int qt = -1;

Matcher matcher = pat2.matcher(Content);
if(matcher.find()) {  //we've found a match
    qt = Integer.parseInt(matcher.group(1));
}
```

or see [this jdoodle](http://jdoodle.com/a/yg).

Comment: I'd say it is overkill if he just needs to get the right part of the colon

Comment: @Dici: mind that later the order of items can be changed, or that there are specific rules on how a SKU looks, etc. by using a pattern you are more confident that you find the correct item.

Comment: I have a philosophy that you should not design for the requirements you think you might have in the future but the requirements you have right now. This leads to simpler systems, and faster development. He might actually never need more than a `substring`. Go to the simplest ! Anyway, he will decide what's best for him

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - It seems working fine for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Dici: sure. I'm not saying regexes are the way to go. An extreme programming approach (like you describe) definitely has its merits.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - Last pattern is for special characters? `([0-9A-Z]+)` ?

Comment: @HelpingHands: yes. It means that the SKU can only consists out of digits (`0`,`1`,...,`9`) and letters (`A`,`B`,...,`Z`).

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - I am trying pattern for `Quantity` , But still it is getting SKU only , I am using pattern **Quantity\\s*:\\s*(\\S*)** , Is it wrong to get Quantity data?

Comment: Yeah , I have did one mistake so. Working fine now. :)

Comment: Do you have any tool in mind which can generate regex pattern based on string? then please suggest.

Comment: @HelpingHands: [regex101](https://regex101.com/) tends to be helpful in explaining and testing regexes. Although it supports PHP, Python and JS regexes which tend to be more expressive than Java ones. Nevertheless it is a good tool to look for a regex.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem - I see. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

You know you can just refer to the length of the string right ?

```
String s   = "SKU: XP321654";
String sku = s.substring(4, s.length()).trim();
```

I think using a regex is clearly overkill in this case, it is way way simpler than this. You can even split the expression although it's a bit less efficient than the solution above, but please don't use a regex for this !

```
String sku = "SKU: XP321654".split(':')[1].trim();
```

Comment: But you also need to get that `s` string from the 3 line string provided in the question. This is incomplete as it is.

Comment: Usually you read a file line by line, I don't think it makes sense to have a string with this format in the first place

Comment: Which is why I asked the OP in the comments before jumping to an answer, and it turns out the input comes as a single string with line breaks.

Answer (score 0):

1: you have to split your input by lines (or split by \n)

2: when you have your line: you search for :  and then you take the remaining of the line (with the String size as mentionned in Dici answer).

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how exactly the string contains new lines, you could do this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    String s = "SKU: XP321654\r\n" + 
               "Quantity: 1\r\n" + 
               "Order date: 01/08/2016";

    System.out.println(s.substring(s.indexOf(": ") + 2, s.indexOf("\r\n")));
}
```

Just note that this 1-liner has several restrictions:

- The `SKU` property has to be first. If not, then modify the start index appropriately to search for `"SKU: "`.
- The new lines might be separated otherwise, `\R` is a regex for all the valid new line escape characters combinations.